# How do I use m2crypto to validate a X509 certificate chain in a non-SSL setting

Tags: python, cryptography, x509certificate, m2crypto, x509

I'm trying to figure out how to, using m2crypto, validate the chain of trust from a public key version of a X509 certificate back to one of a set of known root CA's when the chain may be arbitrarily long. The SSL.Context module looks promising except that I'm not doing this in the context of a SSL connection and I can't see how the information passed to load_verify_locations is used.

Essentially, I'm looking for the interface that's equivalent to:
    openssl verify pub_key_x509_cert

Is there something like that in m2crypto?

Thanks.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/4403012/4279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [patch](https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11690) that might need to be updated slightly, and it would need unit tests for me to check it in. Contributions welcome!

Another convoluted way would be to create an in-memory SSL session where you do the validation. The [Twisted wrapper](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/M2Crypto/SSL/TwistedProtocolWrapper.py) effectively works this way; Twisted acts as dumb network pipe without knowing anything about the data, and M2Crypto encrypts/decrypts the data in memory, doing certificate validation on the side.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified a different M2Crypto patch and with this we are able to verify a X509 Certificate against a chain of CAs, plus it allows the usage of Certificate Revocation List (CRL)s.

The heart of allowing chain verification with M2Crypto is exposing "verify_cert()" on a X509_Store_Context.
Basic flow is:

1. Add your CAs/CRLs to a X509_Store
2. Use a X509_Store_Context to verify the certificate of interest

My patch enhances CRL support as well as allowing chain verification. 
https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12954#c2

We are using this patch as part of Pulp, we have a wiki page below which shares some more info on how we are doing the verification with a chain:
https://fedorahosted.org/pulp/wiki/CertChainVerification

Comment: Additionally we have a set of unittests showing basic chain verification below:
http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=pulp.git;a=blob;f=playpen/certs/chain_example/test_chain_verify.py;hb=HEAD

Scripts to setup the test data are here:
http://git.fedorahosted.org/git/?p=pulp.git;a=tree;f=playpen/certs/chain_example;hb=HEAD