# Retrieve and validate x509 certificate chain

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, x509, m2crypto

I am trying to determine the best way to retrieve and validate a chain of x509 certificates in Python.

If any certificates in the chain are invalid, I need to be able to identify which one specifically and for what reason (like openssl verify at command line). Newer versions of the Python ssl module seem to offer this functionality, however I'm not certain what version will be available where the code is to run.

I have done my best researching similar question on here, specifically

[How do I verify an SSL certificate in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403012/) 
[Validate SSL certificates with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/) 
[How do I use m2crypto to validate a X509 certificate chain in a non-SSL setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626792/)

however I'm still not clear on the best way to go about it.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality (isolating any single invalid certificate) using the builtin ssl module, or would I need to use something like M2Crypto?

If neither of these are appropriate, would a subprocess module call out to openssl be a good alternative solution?

Comment: UPDATE: I wasn't able to get the functionality I wanted out of the Python 2.7.3 ssl module, have decided to use M2Crypto to access the elements off the SSL chain.

Comment: M2Crypto shall grow chain validation (patches already floating around) and OCSP hooks in near future.