# How verify local Cert,Key and CACERT in python and openssl?

Tags: python, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to verify this files by location:

```
ssl_cert =  "/opt/test/my.cert"
ssl_key =  "/opt/test/my.key"
ssl_cacert = "/opt/test/my.cacert"
```

Verification must be not use openssl under bash/sh - only as module.

Please help.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626792/how-do-i-use-m2crypto-to-validate-a-x509-certificate-chain-in-a-non-ssl-setting