# How to validate x509 certificates in Python3

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, x509

Using OpenSSL I can check the validity of user X.509 certificates through the following command:

```
openssl verify -crl_check -CAfile $CRL_chain_path $PEM_path
```

with:

- `$CRL_chain_path`: the path of a base64 file containing the trusted certificate chain and the `CRL` entries
- `$PEM_path`: the path of my base64 certificate to be checked.

How could the same thing be achieved with Python3? So far I'm using the [`cryptography`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library. Unfortunately, according to [this issue](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2381), the functionality is not yet included. Moreover, I would like to avoid `bash` command usage (`subprocess`, `os`, etc.).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700348/how-to-validate-verify-an-x509-certificate-chain-of-trust-in-python) only covers the chain of trust topic (which is unfortunately not enough). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087227/validate-ssl-certificates-with-python) checks SSL/TLS sessions, which cannot be used in my context due to the fact that I focus on user PKI public keys.

Is there a simple way with Python to check the validity of X.509 certificates (date ok, chain of trust, no revocation, any other check performed by `OpenSSL`?, etc.)?